# When do you unlock each shop?

Tags: disgaea-5

Quite a few shops in Disgaea are locked behind level completions and the Strategy Assembly. What are the requirements to unlock all of the shops in the game?

Comment: I deleted my answer because going through a second play through on the same save doesn't tell me when shops unlock, and I'm not going to bother playing a new game over.